# error using php curl with ssl certificate on Centos

Tags: php, ssl, certificate

I am using php with curl to request some API the third-party supplies,as the API doc says,I should request the api with ssl certificate,I do.but the problem is when I run the script on my local environment(mac MAMP),the script works well,but when I deploy the script on my server(centos 6.5),the API can not response correctly,it says "error certificate",how this happen?
the code:

```
public function http_post_xml($data, $url){
        $sslcert_path = self::DATA_PATH.'cert/apiclient_cert.pem';
        $sslkey_path = self::DATA_PATH.'cert/apiclient_key.pem';
        $rootca_path = self::DATA_PATH.'cert/rootca.pem';

        $xml = '<xml>';
        foreach($data as $k=>$v){
            $xml .= "<{$k}>$v</$k>";
        }
        $xml .= '</xml>';

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE,'PEM');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $sslcert_path);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, 'PEM');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $sslkey_path);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $rootca_path);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $rep_xml = simplexml_load_string($response, null);
        $return_code = (String)$rep_xml->return_code;

        return array(
                'code'=>(String)$rep_xml->return_code,
                'msg'=>(String)$rep_xml->return_msg
            );
    }
```

I am sure the certificate path is correct.
sorry for my bad enlish,but please help me....